# How to search for a keyword in an array of objects and copy that object to another array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, search

I'm working on a school assignment and i ran into some trouble. Basically I have an array of objects with a String name attribute, I want to search through that array with a keyword, and pick out any of the objects with that word and store it into another array. I can only use an array, and not arraylist or treemaps, etc. I get a problem where it only gets one of the objects and not the others, the keyword is "is".

this what I have so far:

```
   import java.util.Arrays;
public class TesterTwo
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TestObj t1 = new TestObj("Where is my house",1);
  TestObj t2 = new TestObj("Canada is really cold",2);
  TestObj t3 = new TestObj("It's a big world",3);
  TestObj t4 = new TestObj("What is This",4);
  TestObj t5 = new TestObj("I'm at home",5);
 TestObj[] thingy = new TestObj[]{t1,t2,t3,t4,t5};
  System.out.println("BEFORE");
for(int a = 0; a < thingy.length; a++)
{
  System.out.println(thingy[a].getName());
}
  TestObj [] searchResult = new TestObj[5];

  for (int i = 0; i < thingy.length; i++)
  {
    if(thingy[i].getName().contains("is"))
    {
        int j = 0;
        searchResult[j] = thingy[i];
        j++;
    }else{continue;}
  }
  thingy = searchResult;
System.out.println("After the search has gone through:");
System.out.println("");

for(int i = 0; i < thingy.length; i++){
  if(thingy[i] == null){break;}
    System.out.println(thingy[i].getName());
  }

  }
}
```

EDIT:
I found out i was doing the loop wrong my bad.
Here's my fix:

```
TestObj [] searchResult = new TestObj[thingy.length];

  for (int i = 0, k=0; i < thingy.length; i++)
  {
    if(!thingy[i].getName().contains("is"))
    {
      continue;
    }
    searchResult[k++] = thingy[i];

  }
  thingy = searchResult;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the scope of declared `j` integer variable.
Now you have it declared inside of the `for` loop which makes the scope of `j` available only for a single iteration. At the end of iteration the `j` variable is removed and new iteration makes new one.
Move the declaration of `j` outside of the `for` loop:

```
int j =0;
for (int i = 0; i < thingy.length; i++) 
{
    if(thingy[i].getName().contains("is")) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Additionaly the whole `else` statement is not needed because the `if` statement is kinda last in the loop and if the `if` is false the loop will try to go to the next iteration.

Edit:

The fix you provided has a bit of performance improvement than my original answer. Using second variable in the `for` statement makes it avaiable through all iterations and after the loop is finished the variable will be removed from memory, so to the sample I provide it would be:

```
for (int i = 0, j =0; i < thingy.length; i++) { //...
```

Comment: just saw your edit, seems like my answer is no longer needed?
The fix you provided after the edit looks like to be providing correct results

Comment: You're answer is way better, I'm grateful for your detail post, I fixed it by playing around but didn't really understand what I did wrong. Thank you, I have a better insight now with your explanation.